# Restric access to sendmessage.php

Tags: php, apache, server, phpmailer, contact-form

The message in my contact form gets send via a file called sendmessage.php (phpmailer) once the form fields are validated thanks to bootstrapvalidator.

```
<form action="sendmessage.php" class="well form-horizontal" id="contact_form" method="post" name="contact_form">
```

The issue is that if somebody types `www.mydomain.com/sendmessage.php` directly in their webbrowser, an empty email gets send (so it means that all the fields validation are by-passed).

How can I prevent that?

Many thanks

VALIDATION:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'fa fa-check',
                invalid: 'fa fa-times',
                validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                first_name: {
                    validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre prénom'
                        }
                    }
                },
                 last_name: {
                    validators: {
                         stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre nom'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre adresse e-mail'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                        regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
                        message: 'Veuillez indiquer une adresse e-mail valide'
                                }
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    validators: {
                          stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 1000,
                            message:'Votre message doit faire plus de 10 caractères et moins de 1000.'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Veuillez indiquer votre message'
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }}).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              $('button[name="submit"]').hide();

              var bv = $(this).data('bootstrapValidator');
              // Use Ajax to submit form data
              $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (result) {
                  if (result.status == 1) {
                      $('#success_message').slideDown({
                          opacity: "show"
                      }, "slow")
                      $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
                  } else {
                        $('#error_message').slideDown({
                          opacity: "show"
                      }, "slow")              }
              }, 'json');
          }
            );

    });
```

SENDMESSAGE.PHP

```
<?php


require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$email_vars = array(
    'message' => str_replace("\r\n", '<br />', $_POST['message']),
    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'organisation' => $_POST['organisation'],
    'server' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
    'agent' => $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],

);


//Enable SMTP debugging. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;                               
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "";                 
$mail->Password = "";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->FromName = $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'];


$mail->From = ('mail@');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);



$mail->addAddress("conta");
//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Nouveau message depuis xyz";

$body = file_get_contents('emailtemplate.phtml');

if(isset($email_vars)){
    foreach($email_vars as $k=>$v){
        $body = str_replace('{'.strtoupper($k).'}', $v, $body);
    }
}
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

/* $mail->Body =  $_POST['message']."<br><br>Depuis la page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . "<br>" . $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ; */


$response = array();
if(!$mail->send()) {
  $response = array('message'=>"Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo, 'status'=> 0);
} else {
  $response = array('message'=>"Message has been sent successfully", 'status'=> 1);
}

/* send content type header */
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/* send response as json */
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Check for the submit-button being set in your `sendmessage.php`. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { /* send email */ }`

Comment: Add some sort of Captcha technique, here's one: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: Don't rely on client-side validation only. You *must* do all the same validations server-side as well, or your form may be open to exploitation.

Comment: Thanks Synchro. Since I'm using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer , aren't all the same checks done by phpmailer on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the mailing function in a is postback statement

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

 // put mail function here

} 
 else
 { ?> <h1>Youve reached this page in error</h1> <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

 // put mail function here

} 
 else
 { 
echo '<script>history.go(-2);</script> ';
// you can also use php header function also
// header("Location:form.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when a user accesses your website, you have his IP. if IP == 'your-server-ip' then execute